# Detect inline style left value change and the div has no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there any method to detect the style attribute's left value change. I have a div which has a inline style left value and the value is keep changing and i want to detect that change.

`$("#catalog > div:last-child").children()` is giving me this div

```
[<div style=​"display:​ block;​ position:​ relative;​ padding:​ 0px;​ margin:​ 0px;​ white-space:​ nowrap;​ height:​ 100%;​ left:​ -1641.14px;​">​…​</div>​]
```

The left value is changing continuously and I want to detect change.

P.S. This div does not have any divid and I can only access to that div using `$("#catalog > div:last-child").children()`. I am working for a company and we have a HTML5 tool which is creating a simple catalog ad and all divs are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `left` value by using `$(element).css('left')`. If you want to know change of left then took one global variable and compare previous and present values, if those are different call your function. This function will be in infinite loop.

Example:

```
 var preLeft=0, element = $("#catalog > div:last-child").children(), timer = 200; // You can change based on your requirement
 setInterval(function(){
     if($(element).css('left') != preLeft){
        //your function
        preLeft   = $(element).css('left');
     }
 },200);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have the element selected you can use the .css() method.

```
    $("#catalog > div:last-child").children().css('left');
```

Since you want to continuously want to check the value, this solution depends on how often the function this is in will run, however.

Comment: Anil Talla has a better example of a function that would meet these requirements. (Posted before me too :P)